# Flag specific lines in impala

Tags: sql, impala

Here is my data set:

```
IDX  SESSION_ID
1    Null
2    Null
3    Foo
4    Foo
5    Foo
6    Null
7    Bar
8    Bar
```

I would like to add a flag column which equals 1 if my line is a new session (I define by new session the fact that the session ID change when I order by IDX)

In that case, the output would be :

```
IDX  SESSION_ID  N_Session
1    Null        1
2    Null        0
3    Foo         1
4    Foo         0
5    Foo         0
6    Null        1
7    Bar         1
8    Bar         0
```

How can I do that using impala sql ? (ANSI SQL should be fine too I guess)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT t1.IDX,
       t1.SESSION_ID,
       CASE WHEN t1.IDX = 1 OR
                 t1.SESSION_ID IS NULL AND t2.SESSION_ID IS NOT NULL OR
                 t1.SESSION_ID IS NOT NULL AND t2.SESSION_ID IS NULL OR
                 COALESCE(t1.SESSION_ID, 'a') <> COALESCE(t2.SESSION_ID, 'a')
            THEN 1
            ELSE 0 END AS N_Session
FROM yourTable t1
LEFT JOIN yourTable t2
    ON t1.IDX = t2.IDX + 1
```

Here is a table showing what the temporary result from the join should look like:

```
IDX  SESSION_ID   IDX2   SESSION_ID2   N_Session
1    Null         NULL   NULL          1            <-- first row, 1
2    Null         1      NULL          0            <-- session values agree, 0
3    Foo          2      NULL          1            <-- values different, 1
4    Foo          3      Foo           0
5    Foo          4      Foo           0
6    Null         5      Foo           1            <-- values different, 1
7    Bar          6      NULL          1
8    Bar          7      Bar           0
```

It should be clear that we want to mark `N_Session` with 1 in one of the following two cases:

- the two session IDs do not agree
- the two session IDs agree, but the row is the first row (`IDX` value of 1)

The verbosity of my query arises from having to handle `NULL` values.  If I read your logic correctly, two `NULL` values when compared should actually be treated as the same value, which may not be the case with Impala SQL using certain operators.

Answer (score 1):

```
select  IDX
       ,SESSION_ID

       ,case 
            when    coalesce (SESSION_ID,'') 
                =   lag(coalesce(SESSION_ID,'')) over (order by IDX) 
            then 0 
            else 1 
        end         as N_Session

from    mytable2
;
```

---

```
+-----+------------+-----------+
| idx | session_id | n_session |
+-----+------------+-----------+
| 1   | NULL       | 1         |
| 2   | NULL       | 0         |
| 3   | Foo        | 1         |
| 4   | Foo        | 0         |
| 5   | Foo        | 0         |
| 6   | NULL       | 1         |
| 7   | Bar        | 1         |
| 8   | Bar        | 0         |
+-----+------------+-----------+
```

Comment: This will only work in `CDH 5.2.0 (Impala 2.0.0)` or later.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - Impala 2.0.0 release date was October 2014

Comment: Well then it's a good thing you upgraded in time for your query to work ^ ^